Cannot conditionally split a formula into two lines
I am having a problem splitting a formula into two lines in one of two versions of a paper. The first version (WIDE) uses wide paper while the second uses regular paper. The WIDE version compiles without any problems:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\toggletrue{WIDE}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}
\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\begin{equation*}}{\begin{multline*}}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\end{equation*}}{\end{multline*}}
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.
\end{document}

However, when I comment out the line \toggletrue{WIDE}, the error message is
! LaTeX Error: \begin{multline*} on input line 8 ended by \end{document}.

What am I doing wrong?

The following defines an environment that can nest amsmath-environments by grabbing the contents of the environment itself, and invoking the nested amsmath-environment such that it sees its end. I also provide means to change the used nested environments should that need arise (either by changing the defaults declared in \wideformulaKV or by using an optional argument after the \begin{wideformula} like so: \begin{wideformula}[narrow=align,wide=gather] (though this combination likely makes no sense), in order to be as versatile as your usage of \iftoggle in your MWE). For the key=value part I used expkv-cs (which is my package), but of course the same interface could also be done using ltkeys/l3keys or any other key=value package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\toggletrue{WIDE}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\wideformulaKV\wideformulaOUT
  {%
     narrow = multline
    ,wide   = equation
  }
\newcommand\wideformulaOUT[4]
  {%
    % #1: narrow environment name
    % #2: wide environment name
    % #3: * or empty
    % #4: the environment body
    \iftoggle{WIDE}%
      {\begin{#2#3}#4\end{#2#3}}%
      {\begin{#1#3}#4\end{#1#3}}%
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{wideformula}{O{} b}
  {\wideformulaKV{#1}{}{#2}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{wideformula*}{O{} b}
  {\wideformulaKV{#1}{*}{#2}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:
\begin{wideformula*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula*}
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.

Now I really expect two lines:\togglefalse{WIDE}
\begin{wideformula*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula*}
\end{document}



Some additional explanations:
The environment (regardless of whether it's the starred form or the normal one) will collect the contents inside the argument #2, and an optional argument immediately following \begin{wideformula<*>} inside #1. The remainder of the code works by currying arguments through to \wideformulaOUT, more specifically the environments set up two arguments (the first containing a star or nothing, the second the environment's contents) for \wideformulaOUT's third and fourth argument.
But the immediately called macro is \wideformulaKV. That command is set up by \ekvcSplitAndForward to know two keys (narrow and wide) that it'll split into two arguments and provide \wideformulaOUT with those two arguments. So at first our input looks like this:
\wideformulaKV{<optional argument>}{<star/empty>}{<body>}

and once \wideformulaKV did its thing the input will instead contain
\wideformulaOUT{<narrow-value>}{<wide-value>}{<star/empty>}{<body>}

That macro then picks up all four arguments and evaluates your toggle.
<narrow-value> defaults to multline as set up in \ekvcSplitAndForward, and <wide-value> defaults to equation.

A minimalistic variant of my answer, neither supporting the optional argument nor the unstarred form (so only reproducing your results):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\toggletrue{WIDE}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wideformula*}{b}
  {%
    \iftoggle{WIDE}%
      {\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}%
      {\begin{multline*}#1\end{multline*}}%
  }
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:
\begin{wideformula*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula*}
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.

Now I really expect two lines:\togglefalse{WIDE}
\begin{wideformula*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula*}
\end{document}

Output as above.

Of course you can also add the definition of \NarrowLinebreak to this solution as well.

Thank you! It will take a while for me to understand your solution fully.

@Vlad if you need any explanations just ask.

@Vlad I added a bit of explanations.

Many thanks for the explanations and simplification. I have realized that I do need your full solution.

Skillmon: Your solution has a disadvantage as compared with Willie Wong's. When I run it with a lot of text after the wideformula* environment, the text after the formula becomes indented (there is no empty line before it). Is there a simple way to avoid it?

@Vlad I can't reproduce that indentation and if you take a look at the output-image above the example in my answer doesn't produce an indented following line. so the issue must be in the way you either copied over my code, or in the way you're using it.

Sorry, I have not mastered inserting images in comments yet. It's a tiny indentation, slightly above 1 mm, and it does not show in your image. And it might be visible just on my system.

@Vlad ah, sorry, yes you're correct (and including images in comments isn't possible). That's caused by the space after \end{wideformula}. I edit my code to ignore that space.

@Vlad the \ignorespacesafterend isn't necessary in Willie Wong's answer because environments defined with the environ package automatically add that.

Now it works perfectly for me; thanks a lot.

Is this okay?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\toggletrue{WIDE}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}
\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:

\iftoggle{WIDE}{%
    \begin{equation*}
        \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
        \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
    \end{equation*}
}{%
    \begin{multline*}
        \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }\\
        \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
    \end{multline*}
}


I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.
\end{document}


Thank you for this solution, but I would like to avoid duplicating the formula.

Here's a solution that doesn't require the machinery of the etoolbox package. The following screenshots show the outputs depending on whether WIDE is true or not, respectively. (The framelines indicate the edges of the textblock.)


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifWIDE\WIDEfalse % set up a toggle
\ifWIDE
  \usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} % draw framelines
\else
  \usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around textblock
\fi

\begin{document}

\noindent
This is a very long formula:
\ifWIDE
  \begin{equation*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. 
        And this the second half of my very long formula.}
  \end{equation*}
\else
  \begin{multline*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula.}\\
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
  \end{multline*}
\fi

\noindent
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's concern expressed in the following follow-up comment:

For me, the disadvantage of this solution is that the very long formula is so long that I would like to avoid duplicating it; having it repeated slows me down and is a potential source of errors.

For me, the best way to avoid code duplication and the associated source of errors is not to hard-code the subformulas separately but to define them once as macros (say, in the document's preamble). This would lead to the following modified solution -- no screenshot posted as the output is the same as above):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' and 'multline*' environments
% code the subformulas as macros:
\newcommand\subformulaA{\text{This is the first half of my very long formula.}}
\newcommand\subformulaB{\text{And this the second half of my very long.}}

\newif\ifWIDE\WIDEfalse % set up a toggle
\ifWIDE
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\fi

\begin{document}

\noindent
This is a very long formula:
\ifWIDE
  \begin{equation*}
    \subformulaA 
    \subformulaB
  \end{equation*}
\else
  \begin{multline*}
    \subformulaA \\
    \subformulaB
  \end{multline*}
\fi

\noindent
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.

\end{document}


Thank you. For me, the disadvantage of this solution is that the very long formula is so long that I would like to avoid duplicating it; having it repeated slows me down and is a potential source of errors.

@Vlad - The trouble with your preferred approach is that it cannot work. The display-math environments of the amsmath package, including the multline* environment, are programmed to perform their work in a two-pass process. (Let me know if you're interested in the gory details...) The upshot is that after LaTeX encounters \begin{multline*}, it starts to look ahead for the \end{multline*} statement. If LaTeX cannot find this statement within the current TeX group, it issues the admittedly cryptic error message \begin{multline*} on input line 8 ended by \end{document}.

@Vlad - Please also see the addendum I posted, in which I provide a solution that doesn't involve code duplication and the associated source of errors.

Mico: The idea does not work in my context, I think; the paper becomes more difficult to read, especially that I might have several wide formulas in the end.
I doubt I will be able to understand all the gory details...
Thanks a lot for your help.

With amsmath environments, it is often good to try the environ package, for reasons that Mico explained very well. By defining everything in an environment it also makes the code more readable; for the same reason I suggest using a macro \NarrowLinebreak (or whatever name you choose) instead of typing a \iftoggle statement in the middle of your equation.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\togglefalse{WIDE}
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}

\NewEnviron{wideformula}{%
    \iftoggle{WIDE}{\def\NarrowLinebreak{}%
        \begin{equation*}
            \BODY
        \end{equation*}}{\def\NarrowLinebreak{\\}%
        \begin{multline*}
            \BODY
        \end{multline*}}}

\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:
\begin{wideformula}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \NarrowLinebreak
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula}
I expect to see 1 line if WIDE and 2 lines otherwise.
\end{document}


Nowadays I'd suggest using \NewDocumentEnvironment and the b-argument over environ.

@Skillmon: good point; old habits however die hard.

Thank you, it's a beautiful solution. I have only replaced "\def" by "\newcommand" (just in case). And I will read about \NewDocumentEnvironment.

@Vlad since the definition of \NarrowLinebreak is local to this environment the \def is fine actually, it can't leak or overwrite anything outside the environment. If you're still worried, the \newcommand is fine as well.

@Skillmon: thank you, it makes sense to me. I have realized that your solution works better for me (I will need both starred and unstarred wide formulas), so I have accepted it. (Alas, I can't accept two solutions; Willie Wong's also fully answers my original question.)

Here's my suggestion: using \eqbreak instead of \\.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox,lipsum}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
%\toggletrue{WIDE}

\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{varequation*}{b}
 {%
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{%
    \makeequation{equation*}{#1}{}%
  }{%
    \makeequation{multline*}{#1}{\\}%
  }%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeequation}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \eqbreak } {#2}
  \begin{#1} \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#3} \end{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{varequation*}
\text{This is the first half of my very long formula.}
  \eqbreak
\text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{varequation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


If I uncomment the \toggletrue{WIDE} line:


In the end I settled on Willie Wong's simple solution. This is a slightly edited version:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox,environ}
\newtoggle{WIDE}
\toggletrue{WIDE} % comment out for wide paper
\iftoggle{WIDE}{\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}}{}

\NewEnviron{wideformula}{%
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}%
     {\begin{multline}\BODY\end{multline}}}
\NewEnviron{wideformula*}{%
  \iftoggle{WIDE}{\begin{equation*}\BODY\end{equation*}}%
    {\begin{multline*}\BODY\end{multline*}}}
\newcommand{\NarrowLinebreak}{\iftoggle{WIDE}{}{\\}}

\begin{document}
This is a very long formula:
\begin{wideformula}\label{eq:long}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \NarrowLinebreak
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula}
We should see one line if WIDE and two lines otherwise.
And we do not want any indentation after the formula.

Equation~\eqref{eq:long} is numbered,
but there is also a starred version:
\begin{wideformula*}
  \text{This is the first half of my very long formula. }
  \NarrowLinebreak
  \text{And this the second half of my very long formula.}
\end{wideformula*}
Similarly to \eqref{eq:long},
we see one line if WIDE and two lines otherwise.
And there is no indentation after the formula.

